# Trying to add a database to my xampp local host but cmd cannot find the file path

Tags: mysql, cmd, path, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to export my site to a local host so I can create a test environment to test new features I want to create but I've been having problems importing the database. I've also tried using plugins like duplicator but the site is too big to download it that way. I've also tried to import it via phpMyAdmin using the import tab but after fixing some issues with the max upload size it still does not work and gives me all sorts of syntax errors so I've decided my best option is to import it directly with cmd.

Here is the problem...

I run this in CMD:

`C:\Users\daniel>mysql -u root -p eurolootest < C:\User\Daniel\Desktop\euroloodatabase.sql.zip`

But I get this error: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Could someone help me fix this issue as I'm sure I'm using the correct path or give me an alternative option to transfer my site to my localhost?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to CD into the Xampp MySql directory. 
It would be the place you installed xampp (default C:)

e.g. `cd "C:\xampp\mysql\bin"`

and then run your command from here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works but now I have this problem... It asks for a password but I've not set a password for the database so I leave it blank and it gives me another error - ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: 'PK'.

Comment: You can try running with the option `--binary-mode`, this not a an error I encountered before however.

Comment: Binary mode did not work.... I now get this error:  at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'PK' at line 1 
- at least I got over the first hurdle... I'll have a look round to see if I can resolve this issue